# Cypher query timeout trying get all nodes

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

first of all, I'm sorry my poor English and I'm newbie in Neo4J!

I have a graph database modelled like Twitter social network.

```
Nodes: Users and Tweets
Relationships: :WROTE, :RETWEETED, :FOLLOWED
```

I have about 2.2M nodes, 8.1M properties and 1.4M relationships.

I need to get all unique screen names of Users who wrote or retweeted a tweet.

So, I was using this query until my database get bigger:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[]-(t:Tweet) return distinct u.screen_name;
```

Now the problem is this query returning timeout.

How would this query for better performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of Neo4J are you using?

Comment: Hi @MarcoCI Neo4J Version 2.0.1

Comment: Now i'm executing this query: _"MATCH (u:User)-[:WROTE|RETWEETED]->(t:Tweet) RETURN distinct u.screen_name SKIP 0 LIMIT 1000;"_ in a FOR loop on Python. But I still want to know if exists any query to get all screen_names in only one execution...

Answer (score 0):

How many users do you have? You'll probably return too much data for the browser.

Can you try these queries:

```
MATCH (u:User) return count(*);

MATCH (u:User) return u.screen_name;

MATCH (u:User) WHERE (u)-[:WROTE|RETWEETED]->() return u.screen_name LIMIT 1000;

MATCH (u:User) WHERE (u)-[:WROTE|RETWEETED]->() return u.screen_name;
```